# Python Windows pip install failure: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

Trying to install the cld2-cffi module within Python 3.4 on Windows 7 x64 fails on my desktop machine.

I've tried repairing and restarting Visual Studio 2015, and running vcvarsall.bat again, but no luck. Unfortunately, this module is not on Christophe Gohlke's list of compled .whl files.

Here's the error message:

```
 Installing 'cld2-cffi' -----
Collecting cld2-cffi
  Using cached cld2-cffi-0.1.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\cld2_cffi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    _cffi__x21af333bx25bdf976.c
    encoding_lut.cc
    binding.cc
    cld2\binding.cc(165) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
    cldutil.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cldutil_shared.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    compact_lang_det.cc
    compact_lang_det_hint_code.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\compact_lang_det_hint_code.cc(1450) : warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
    cld2\internal\compact_lang_det_hint_code.cc(1516) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
    compact_lang_det_impl.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\compact_lang_det_impl.cc(2117) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
    debug.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\debug.cc(92) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
    cld2\internal\debug.cc(255) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
    cld2\internal\debug.cc(264) : warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
    fixunicodevalue.cc
    generated_entities.cc
    generated_language.cc
    generated_ulscript.cc
    getonescriptspan.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\getonescriptspan.cc(473) : warning C4800: 'const char' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
    lang_script.cc
    offsetmap.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\offsetmap.cc(73) : warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\stdio.h(234) : see declaration of 'fopen'
    scoreonescriptspan.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    tote.cc
    utf8statetable.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2\internal\utf8statetable.cc(288) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
    cld2\internal\utf8statetable.cc(382) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
    cld2\internal\utf8statetable.cc(472) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
    cld_generated_cjk_uni_prop_80.cc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
    cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc
    cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_32.cc
    generated_distinct_bi_0.cc
    cld2_generated_quad0122.cc
    cld2_generated_deltaocta0122.cc
    cld2_generated_distinctocta0122.cc
    cld_generated_score_quad_octa_0122.cc
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 639, in link
        self.spawn([self.linker] + ld_args)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
        _spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 81, in _spawn_nt
        "command %r failed with exit status %d" % (cmd, rc))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 58, in _build
        dist.run_command('build_ext')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 75, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 535, in build_extension
        target_lang=language)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 717, in link_shared_object
        extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 641, in link
        raise LinkError(msg)
    distutils.errors.LinkError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xet8gtog\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 191, in <module>
        'Topic :: Text Processing :: Linguistic'
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 279, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 294, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 525, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 561, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\py36compat.py", line 34, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 133, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 34, in finalize_options
        orig.build_py.finalize_options(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_py.py", line 45, in finalize_options
        ('force', 'force'))
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 287, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xet8gtog\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 143, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xet8gtog\cld2-cffi\setup.py", line 128, in get_ext_modules
        import cld2
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xet8gtog\cld2-cffi\cld2\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
        extra_compile_args=_COMPILER_ARGS)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 437, in verify
        lib = self.verifier.load_library()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 113, in load_library
        self._compile_module()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 210, in _compile_module
        outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile(tmpdir, self.get_extension())
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 29, in compile
        outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 65, in _build
        raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
    cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: LinkError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xet8gtog\cld2-cffi\
----- Failed to install 'cld2-cffi' -----
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 standalone](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)? I assume your issue could be you're trying to compile on a 64-bit machine with Visual Studio Express which only provides a x86 compiler.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I was compiling on a 64-bit machine that only had the x86 compiler.