# Python Windows Pip install failure with exit code 1104 and building wheel failure

Tags: python, python-wheel

I am working in a Python environment in Anaconda. When using the command `pip install jwst` I initially obtained the error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is recquired", which persisted even after I downloaded the most recent version of Visual Studio Build Tools. I followed a suggestion given in the answer to a similar question and wrote `pip install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2`.

Now, I get a different error:

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: could not open file 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l5rn428c\drizzle_7ef4190d35d0411caabe45eb6792130b\src\cdrizzle.cp311-win_amd64.exp'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for drizzle
Failed to build drizzle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for drizzle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I found a question that's [similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956090/python-windows-pip-install-failure-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-st) in which someone suggests that the error is caused by a x86 version of Visual Studio Build Tools being used on a 64-bit computer. It does seem that my version on Visual Studio Build Tools uses a 32-bit compiler, however I can't seem to find a different version. The thread is also quite old, so I'm not sure if this would work in the first place.

Comment: It's possible that "wheel" isn't installed. Try running "pip install wheel" as suggested over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install

Comment: Thank you, but I've already done this too. I tried it again just to make sure and it said "Requirement already satisfied".